# Can't seem to figure out how to execute stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is my SQL code on getting a customers id to generate it with all of the orders that they made. I cant seem to figure out how to execute it properly. Example:

```
EXEC CustOrder(1000)
```

Shouldn't this mean the same as `where cc.cus_id =1000` ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustOrder(cusid in number)
is 

BEGIN
  SELECT cc.Cus_ID,cc.cus_name,o.Order_ID
  FROM Customer cc
  JOIN orderitem o ON cc.cust_id = o.cust_id 
  WHERE cc.cus_id = cusid;
END;
```

Comment: I am getting PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
Errors: check compiler log when trying to do EXEC CustOrder(1000); My desired output is the customer id the chosen id and all of their orders

Comment: Please, do not use comments to add more details to the question. SO is not a forum, so you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66131499/edit) your question and add as much new details as needed to make it answerable.

Comment: Why do you need to get multiple rows with PL/SQL instead of just executing `select` statement against `orderitem ` with filted on `cust_id`? PL/SQL consumes more resources for such trivial task. If you need only `cust_id` and `order_id`s of the customer in the output there's no need to join something.

Answer (score 0):

As Oracle says - in PL/SQL you need an `INTO` clause. So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE custorder (cusid IN NUMBER)
IS
   l_cus_name  customer.cus_name%TYPE;
   l_order_id  orderitem.order_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT cc.cus_name, o.order_id
     INTO l_cus_name, l_order_id
     FROM customer cc JOIN orderitem o ON cc.cust_id = o.cust_id
    WHERE cc.cus_id = cusid;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_ine (l_cus_name || ': ' || l_order_id);
END;
```

You don't have to select `cc.cus_id` as you already know it - you passed it as a parameter, right?

Comment: "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" for single rowed values i could get the value i needed but for multiple rows i am getting this type of error. is there any way to combine for both?

Comment: TOO_MANY_ROWS happens when there are more than a single row for condition applied to SELECT statement. In your case, there are at least two rows whose CC.CUS_ID = CUSID. You can handle it, but the question is *how* - what would you want to do in that case? Return only one value? If so, which one? If you want to accept the fact that there are many rows involved, you could use a loop, or (bulk) insert into a collection. So, as I said, it just *depends*.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thank you so much for your time answering my question. I think I can get the flow of it already :)